# Best way to set a multiindex on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe `df` with these columns:

```
Group
Year
Gender
Feature_1
Feature_2
Feature_3
...
```

I want to use MultiIndex to stack the data later, and I tried this way:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['Group'], df['Year'], df['Gender']])
```

This instruction successfully makes MultiIndex for my Dataframe, but is there a better way that also removes the original columns?

Comment: use `df = df.set_index(['Group', 'Year', 'Gender'])`

Comment: Thanks, if you could write is as answer I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Indexing in pandas is easier than this. You do not need to create your own instance of the MultiIndex class.

The pandas DataFrame has a method called `.set_index()` which takes either a single column as argument or a list of columns. Supplying a list of columns will set a multiindex for you.

Like this:

```
df.set_index(['Group', 'Year', 'Gender'], inplace=True)
```

Note the `inplace=True`, which I can recommend highly.

When you are dealing with huge dataframes that barely fit in memory, inplace operations will *litterally half* your memory usage.

Consider this:

```
df2 = df1.set_index('column') # Don't do this
del df1 # Don't do this
```

When this operation is done, the memory usage will be about the same as before. But only because we do `del df1`. In the time between these two commands, there will be two copies of the same dataframe, therefore, double memory.

Doing this is *implicitly the same*:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('column') # Don't do this either
```

And will still take double memory of doing this inplace.